# (SOLVED) HC-06 not responding to AT command

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, usart

I am using an Arduino R3 Mega 2560. I have an HC-06 Bluetooth Module connected as shown below:

HC-06 | Mega R3

VCC--330-ohm - 5V

GND ---- GND

TXD ---- RX, 0

RXD ---- TX, 1

When I input 'AT' (without quotes) into the serial monitor at 9600 baud, the module does not respond.

I am not paired with the module as it is blinking rapidly.

I don't know if this is related but the Arduino board is powered using a USB cable connected to my computer.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Answered the question below.

Comment: You've attached the HC-06 to the same pins that are being used for the serial monitor.  Use Serial1 for the HC-06 and write code to send what's read from the serial monitor back out there.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Added the solution to the post.

Comment: @BarelyDeveloper hey, it would be better to post your solution as an answer and select it as accepted one. You can do it, even though you asked the question in the first place. This would make it easier for others to find your solution and would give you some sweet points as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to Delta_G, I got the module to work (after a bit of irritation.) Here is the code:

```
 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Enter AT command.");

  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());
  }

}
```

This is assuming that the HC-06 default baud rate is at 9600. When I typed 'AT' without line endings (so the None option in the Serial Monitor), it returned "OK." Again, "AT" with line endings did not work for me. If this is not the case with someone else, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

You've attached the HC-06 to the same pins that are being used for the serial monitor. Use Serial1 for the HC-06 and write code to send what's read from the serial monitor back out there.